# Rotate a color channel when rendering an object in OpenGL

Tags: opengl

Am wondering how to convert the red channel to blue when rendering some objects in OpenGL.

I can do this easily using a fragment shader but unfortunately I can't use shaders for this particular project.

```
Rotate red and blue channels
DrawOject();
Disable Rotate red and blue channels
```

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: What version of OpenGL are you using?

Comment: I'm using version OpenGL 2.0